# Issue with dropDuplicates() and except() method in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table with colum
xcept(filteredDuplicates)

When I run this in Spark shell, it is working perfectly fine as expected. But in spark submit, the duplicate removal is not in the sorted order (ie) seq_no 3 is in valid frame and 1,5 in rejected frame. Also, except() is also having issue in spark submit. I am stuck with this for a whole day,please someone help
   Thanks for everyone in advance

Comment: I don't think `dropDuplicates` provides any guarantee to keep the _first_ record for every group of duplicates - at least there's no such guarantee in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@dropDuplicates()). I'd assume it only works in Spark Shell "by chance" (there's only one partition, maybe?). You'd have to find a different approach, e.g. using `groupBy`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I got a solution for this by using group by. But still don't know exactly what's the issue. It will be better if the documentation is improved

Answer (score 0):

The following methods generates the valid and invalid dataframes using the row_number function provided by spark-sql. I dont have access to cassandra so I am using a simple Dataframe here.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a" -> 1), ("b" -> 2), ("c" -> 3), ("d" -> 4), ("a" -> 5), ("a" -> 6), ("c" -> 7), ("c" -> 8))).toDF("c1", "c2")

df.registerTempTable("temp_table")

val masterdf = sqlContext.sql("SELECT c1, c2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c2) as row_num FROM temp_table")

masterdf.filter("row_num = 1").show()
+---+---+-------+
| c1| c2|row_num|
+---+---+-------+
|  a|  1|      1|
|  b|  2|      1|
|  c|  3|      1|
|  d|  4|      1|
+---+---+-------+


masterdf.filter("row_num > 1").show()
+---+---+-------+
| c1| c2|row_num|
+---+---+-------+
|  a|  5|      2|
|  a|  6|      3|
|  c|  7|      2|
|  c|  8|      3|
+---+---+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My issue is somehow different from your answer but anyway,got solution for this issue